# How can I run arbitrarily complex command using sudo over ssh?

Tags: ssh, bash, scripting, sudo

I have a system that I can only log in to under my username (myuser), but I need to run commands as other user (scriptuser). So far, I have come up with the following to run the commands I need:

```
ssh -tq myuser@hostname "sudo -u scriptuser bash -c \"ls -al\""
```

If however, when I try to run a more complex command, such as `[[ -d "/tmp/Some directory" ]] && rm -rf "/tmp/Some directory"` I quickly get into trouble with quoting. I'm not sure how I could pass this example complex command to `bash -c`, when `\"` already delimites the boundaries of the command I'm passing (and so I don't know how to quote /tmp/Some directory, which includes a spaces.

Is there a general solution allowing me to pass any command no matter how complex/crazy the quoting is, or is this some sort of limitation I have reached? Are there other possible and perhaps more readable solutions?

Comment: Copy a script to $remote then execute it.

Comment: That would work, but I find a solution which leaves no script files behind (in case something fails etc.) would be a bit cleaner.

Comment: have the script rm itself at end of each run

Comment: Consider to use fabric http://www.fabfile.org/. Can make you life much easier if you have to sudo remotely a lot.

Comment: Can we assume you've set up `sudo` so that it does not require a pasword prompt?

Comment: fabric or ansible is the way to go. Consider to use something like this.

Comment: If you have Ansible installed this command shows the documentation for your use case: ansible-doc script

Comment: You could try something like [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1315213/41861) to a [question for dealing with embedded quotes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1250079/41861)

Answer (score 154, accepted):

A trick I use sometimes is to use base64 to encode the commands, and pipe it to bash on the other site:

```
MYCOMMAND=$(base64 -w0 script.sh)
ssh user@remotehost "echo $MYCOMMAND | base64 -d | sudo bash"
```

This will encode the script, with any commas, backslashes, quotes and variables inside a safe string, and send it to the other server. (`-w0` is required to disable line wrapping, which happens at column 76 by default).  On the other side, `$(base64 -d)` will decode the script and feed it to bash to be executed.

I never got any problem with it, no matter how complex the script was. Solves the problem with escaping, because you don't need to escape anything. It does not creates a file on the remote host, and you can run vastly complicated scripts with ease.

Comment: Or even: `ssh user@remotehost "echo \`base64 -w0 script.sh\` | base64 -d | sudo bash"`

Comment: It's worth noting that in most cases you can substitute lzop or gzip for base64 for faster transfer times. However, there may be edge cases. YMMV.

Comment: Good note, but if it's a script, I don't expect any transfer to be more than a few kb.

Comment: There's a useless use of echo in here too. `base64 script | ssh remotehost 'base64 -d | sudo bash'` would be enough :)

Comment: While I haven't tested this solution, will it output result of the script, say for example 'yum check-update' in the stdout? I wanted to ask because if someone thinks I am doing something obviously naive, I can pick up few things.

Comment: What if I'm using a sudosh filter? How do I then run an arbitarily complex command?

Answer (score 36):

See the `-tt` option? Read the `ssh(1)` manual.

```
ssh -tt root@host << EOF
sudo some # sudo shouldn't ask for a password, otherwise, this fails. 
lines
of
code 
but be careful with \$variables
and \$(other) \`stuff\`
exit # <- Important. 
EOF
```

One thing I often do is use vim and use the `:!cat % | ssh -tt somemachine` trick.

Comment: Of course `:!cat % | (command)` can be done as `:w !(command)` or `:!(command) < %`.

Comment: Yes. My line is a [cat abuse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat)

Comment: running `ssh -tt` causes my ssh to not terminate after certain commands are run (adding `exit` at the end doesn't help)

Answer (score 10):

I think the easiest solution lies in a modification of @thanasisk's comment.

Create a script, `scp` it to the machine, then run it.

Have the script `rm` itself at the start. The shell has opened the file, so it's been loaded, and can then be removed without problems.

By doing things in this order (`rm` first, other stuff second) it'll even be removed when it fails at some point.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the `%q` format specifier with `printf` to take care of the variable escaping for you:

```
cmd="ls -al"
printf -v cmd_str '%q' "$cmd"
ssh user@host "bash -c $cmd_str"
```

`printf -v` writes the output to a variable (in this case, `$cmd_str`). I think that this is the simplest way to do it. There's no need to transfer any files or encode the command string (as much as I like the trick).

Here's a more complex example showing that it works for things like square brackets and ampersands too:

```
$ ssh user@host "ls -l test"
-rw-r--r-- 1 tom users 0 Sep  4 21:18 test
$ cmd="[[ -f test ]] && echo 'this really works'"
$ printf -v cmd_str '%q' "$cmd"
$ ssh user@host "bash -c $cmd_str"
this really works
```

I haven't tested it with `sudo` but it should be as simple as:

```
ssh user@host "sudo -u scriptuser bash -c $cmd_str"
```

If you want, you can skip a step and avoid creating the intermediate variable:

```
$ ssh user@host "bash -c $(printf '%q' "$cmd")"
this really works
```

Or even just avoid creating a variable entirely:

```
ssh user@host "bash -c $(printf '%q' "[[ -f test ]] && echo 'this works as well'")"
```

Comment: this is an awesome solution. I've actually had to use printf before for a similar situation, but I always forget about it. Thanks for posting this :-)

Answer (score 9):

UPDATE: Examples now explicitly use `sudo`.

Here's a way to use Bash syntax with compound assignments to execute arbitrarily complex commands over SSH with sudo:

```
CMD=$( cat <<'EOT'
echo "Variables like '${HOSTNAME}' and commands like $( whoami )"
echo "will be interpolated on the server, thanks to the single quotes"
echo "around 'EOT' above."
EOT
) \
SSHCMD=$(
  printf 'ssh -tq myuser@hostname sudo -u scriptuser bash -c %q' "${CMD}" ) \
bash -c '${SSHCMD}'

CMD=$( cat <<EOT
echo "If you want '${HOSTNAME}' and $( whoami ) to be interpolated"
echo "on the client instead, omit the the single quotes around EOT."
EOT
) \
SSHCMD=$(
  printf 'ssh -tq myuser@hostname sudo -u scriptuser bash -c %q' "${CMD}" ) \
bash -c '${SSHCMD}'
```

Formatting commands properly to be executed dynamically somewhere else (e.g. nested shells, remote SSH shells, etc.) can be very tricky - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53197638/111948 for a good description of why.  Complicated bash structures, like the syntax above, can help these commands work properly.

For more information about how `cat` and `<<` combine to form inline *here documents*, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/21761956/111948

Comment: The question asks for a single `sudo` command.

Comment: @PedroVagner - thanks for pointing that out, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This one gets my vote for the sheer amount of black magic in it!

Answer (score 5):

Are you aware that you can use `sudo` to give you a shell where you can run commands as the chosen user?

> -i, --login
>
> Run the shell specified by the target user's password database entry as a login shell.  This means that login-specific resource files such as
>                    .profile or .login will be read by the shell.  If a command is specified, it is passed to the shell for execution via the shell's -c option.  If no
>                    command is specified, an interactive shell is executed.  sudo attempts to change to that user's home directory before running the shell.  The com‐
>                    mand is run with an environment similar to the one a user would receive at log in.  The Command Environment section in the sudoers(5) manual docu‐
>                    ments how the -i option affects the environment in which a command is run when the sudoers policy is in use.

Comment: this seems like the obvious solution to me.
> sudo -i -u brian

Comment: That works best when combined with "ssh -t" in the case of remote access.  Which is included in the question, but bears repeating for the "I can't read this /whole/ page" folks. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can define the script on your local machine and then `cat` and pipe it to the remote machine:

```
user@host:~/temp> echo "echo 'Test'" > fileForSsh.txt
user@host:~/temp> cat fileForSsh.txt | ssh localhost

Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
Test
```

Comment: UUOC you can use <

Comment: Can you modify the example to include `sudo -u scriptuser`? Would heredoc be usable considering I need to have variables in the script I'd be piping to the machine?

Comment: I was trying: `echo "sudo \`cat fileForSsh.txt\`" | ssh ...` but I keep getting `sudo: sorry, you must have a tty to run sudo`.

Comment: Although [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/116654/running-sudo-over-ssh) may help if you can get the `/etc/sudoers` file changed

Comment: This works for me: `ssh -tq user@host "sudo bash -s" < test.sh`

Answer (score 3):

**Simple and easy.**

> ssh user@servidor "bash -s" < script.sh

Answer (score 1):

If you use a sufficiently modern Bash shell, you could put your commands in a function and print that function as a string using `export -p -f function_name`. The result of that string can then contain arbitrary commands that do not necessarily have to run as root.

An example using pipes from [my answer on Unix.SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/148748/8250):

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
> remote_main() {
>    local dest="$HOME/destination"
>
>    tar xzv -C "$dest"
>    chgrp -R www-data "$dest"
>    # Ensure that newly written files have the 'www-data' group too
>    find "$dest" -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \;
> }
> tar cz files/ | ssh user@host "$(declare -pf remote_main); remote_main"
> ```

An example that retrieves saves the file for the login user and installs a program a root:

```
remote_main() {
    wget https://example.com/screenrc -O ~/.screenrc
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install screen
}
ssh user@host "$(declare -pf remote_main); remote_main"
```

If you would like to run the whole command using `sudo`, you could use this:

```
remote_main() {
    wget https://example.com/screenrc -O ~user/.screenrc
    apt-get update && apt-get install screen
}
ssh user@host "$(declare -pf remote_main);
    sudo sh -c \"\$(declare -pf remote_main); remote_cmd\""
# Alternatively, if you don't need stdin and do not want to log the command:
ssh user@host "$(declare -pf remote_main);
    (declare -pf remote_main; echo remote_cmd) | sudo sh"
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my (not really tested) crappy solution for this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# shell-escape: Escape each argument.
ARGV.each do|a|
  print " '#{a.gsub("'","\'\\\\'\'")}' "
end
```

Not you can do:

```
ssh -tq myuser@hostname "$(shell-escape sudo -u scriptuser bash -c "$(shell-escape ls -al)")"
```

The next step is to create a `betterssh` script which already does this:

```
betterssh -tq myuser@hostname sudo -u scriptuser bash -c "$(shell-escape ls -al)"
```

Answer (score 1):

For these of you who needs to pass parameters to the script it should be as follows:

```
ssh user@remotehost "echo `base64 -w0 script.sh` | base64 -d | sudo bash -s <param1> <param2> <paramN>"
```

Answer (score 1):

First, create a local script and then execute it remotely using the follow command:

```
cat <Local Script.sh> | ssh user@server "cat - | sudo -u <user> /bin/bash"
```