# While loop does not return control

Tags: ssh, shell-scripting

The following shell script works only for first server and does not loop to the next.
I tried 0< before the ssh command but it still does not return to the shell script once connected.

```
#!/bin/sh
while read IP
do
ssh root@10.0.0.10 " ssh root@$IP 'ls -lht /log/cdr-csv/ ' " > /tmp/$IP.txt
done << here_doc
18.17.6.19
18.17.10.24
here_doc
```

How do I run the same command on the second server 18.17.10.24 ?

Comment: It seems likely that your SSH connection to the first server is not existing for some reason.  Add a `set -x` to the top of your script.  Where does it stop?

Comment: and for more fun debugging output, `ssh -v`

Comment: 0< /dev/null ssh root@10.0.0.10 This is the correct answer to this question. Someone from server fault has answered before. I posted this as answer and it was deleted by Moderator who claims to be "system administrator since time out of mind".

Comment: @shantanuo: You just posted a line of code without context and it was unclear what you meant. You have used [SF] more than long enough and should know that this is not a proper way to answer, even for your own question. If you would post a proper answer with an explanation, it wouldn't get deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You should send to the remote server the script to be executed. The way your script is written will not work because the `here_doc` is evaluated locally, not remotely.

Take a look on [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/625641/how-can-i-run-arbitrarily-complex-command-using-sudo-over-ssh/625697#625697) I provided to another user on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh` reads stdin unless you provide the `-n` option. So, the first IP address is consumed by `read IP` and all the rest of the here-doc is consumed by `ssh root@10.0.0.10`. Change that to `ssh -n root@10.0.0.10`